# Can a url link be shared from iOS app via FB Messenger without presenting UIActivityViewController dialog and not needing Facebook SDK?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, share, messenger

I am wondering if it is possible to share/send a url link and other media from iOS app via Facebook Messenger app without having to open `UIActivityViewController`'s activity sheet first, which in addition shows a number of other apps which can handle the intended data and does not allow to exclude apps only `UIActivityType`s. I would like to present a FB Messenger dialog with pre-filled url link immediately after a button tap, so no dialog with multiple other apps.

Facebook documentation suggests we should use FB SDK in such cases: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios#message. But what is beyond me is that iOS seems to have a "native access" to the Messenger app (and other apps), but there is no good API which could facilitate some UI customisation.

Any idea if there is a way to directly open FB Messenger with pre-filled message without needing to present `UIActivityViewController`'s activity sheet or installing FB SDK?

EDIT: Let me clarify, I would like to share a url link or other media, it is not necessary that the message is pre-filled with text.

Comment: Prefilling a message is not allowed by Facebook Platform Policy

Comment: Stupid Facebook wants us to integrate their SDK so they removed the URL Scheme support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of searching I can confirm that it is not possible to share text or other media via Facebook Messenger without using their FB SDK as they do not provide URL schemes for that.

Answer (score 3):

You can share a link via messenger in this way

```
let urlStr = String(format: "fb-messenger://share/?link=%@", sharelink!)
let url  = NSURL(string: urlStr)

if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url! as URL) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url! as URL, options: [:]) { (success) in
        if success {
            print("Messenger accessed successfully")
        } else {
            print("Error accessing Messenger")
        }
    }
} else {
    // show Install Messenger
}
```

Comment: As of May 2020, can confirm this is possible and should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This only works if links need to be shared. If text need to be shared then?